# Java Game with JavaFX Canvas | Canvas stops updating

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I use Java to create a game with the JavaFX Canvas.

I pass the Canvas graphicsContext to my GameLoop, which launches an extra thread. From there, I pass my graphicsContext via an ObjectHandler to every object that is to be drawn on the canvas.

It works that way for a while, but then the canvas somehow stops and no object is redrawn. The game is still running in the background. At the logs I can see that all objects continue to run and be updated.
 
Does anyone have an idea why this may be or how I could solve it?

This is my part from my Window Class:

```
canvas = new Canvas(Config.getCANVAS_WIDTH(), Config.getCANVAS_HEIGHT());
canvas.setFocusTraversable(true);
gc = new GameContainer(canvas.getGraphicsContext2D(), canvas);
primaryStage.setTitle(gc.getTitle());
primaryStage.setResizable(false);
```

This is part from my Gameloop:

```
if (render) {
    gc.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    handler.render(gc);
    gc.setFill(Color.GRAY);
    if (Config.isDebug()) {
         debugText.printDebug(fps);
    }
    frames++;
}
```

The HandlerClass is only a list with an arrayList  and two loops (for ticks and render).
This is an example for an a typical render function

```
public void render(GraphicsContext gc) {
    gc.save();
    gc.translate(x, y);
    gc.rotate(rotation);
    gc.setFill(Color.RED);
    gc.fillRect(-4, -4, 8, 8);
    gc.restore();
}
```

Comment: Give us something to work with. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JKostikiadis updated

Comment: The ui needs to be modified from the javafx application thread, since there's no synchronisation of the data of nodes. I guess what happens in your case is that after a few updates java determines that it can improve performance, if the canvas data is no longer shared between both threads but that each thread uses it's own copy of the data. (Java is allowed to do this unless you specifically tell it not to do this which is not possible in this case.)

Comment: so teh best way to do this, is to bring teh render function into the Javafx thread and the tick should stay into the Gameloop right? @fabian

Comment: Maybe take a look at [`AnimationTimer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html).

Comment: I have used the AnimationTimer, but after a short time the FPS fell from stable 60FPS to 20FPS, sometimes less.
The CPU utilization has been at 120%. Maybe I did something wrong there but the only methods I had in there was the tick () and the render () method @Jai

Comment: I now have Platform.runLater (() -> {});
stand in each render () method. It now seems to continue, but now I sometimes have a short suspension in which nothing is rendered.

Comment: It has been resolved. I forgot it at one point.

Answer (score 1):

The drawing on the canvas with the GraphicsContext must be in

```
Platform.runLater (() -> {});
```

See [JavavFX is not thread safe](https://medium.com/@mglover/concurrency-in-javafx-32a5f6133d)